# Extract Date And Hour Only From Date Time Field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running `SQL Server 2008` and I have a `datetime` field, from this field I only want to extract the date and hour.  I tried to parse out using `datepart()` but I think I did it incorrectly as when I attempted to string the two back together I got a number value.  What I attempted was

```
Select Datepart(YEAR, '12/30/2015 10:57:00.000') + 
       Datepart(HOUR, '12/30/2015 10:57:00.000')
```

And what was returned was `2025`  What I want to see returned is

```
12/30/2015 10:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `DATEADD` and `DATEDIFF`:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '12/30/2015 10:57:00.000';

SELECT DATEADD(second,DATEDIFF(second,'1970-01-01',@d)/3600*3600 , '1970-01-01')
-- 2015-12-30 10:00:00
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/417690)**</kbd>

How it works:

1. Get seconds difference from `1970-01-01`
2. Divide by 3600 (integer division so the part after decimal point will be skipped)
3. Multiply by 3600 to get value back to full hours
4. Add calculated seconds number to `1970-01-01`

---

With `SQL Server 2012+` the neat way is to use [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx):

```
SELECT DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@d), MONTH(@d), DAY(@d), DATEPART(HOUR, @d),0,0,0)
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/417691)**</kbd>

Comment: why did you divide by 3600*3600?

Comment: @FartStopper Added explanation